# PDO query in extended class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, extends

Below is the db connection class, but I am going to improve it by extending the PDO class itself:

```
<?php

class db{


private static $instance = NULL;

public function __construct() {
}

public static function getInstance() {

if (!self::$instance)
{
self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbmvc", 'root', '');;
self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
return self::$instance;
}


private function __clone(){
}

}

?>
```

extended class:

```
<?php 

class Model extends db{


final public function fetchInfo() 
{

global $pdo, $db;

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM table");
$query->execute();

$result = $query -> fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) 
{
echo $row['name'];
}

}
}

?>
```

But I have errors when I call this method:

```
 $model=new Model();
 $model->fetchInfo();
```

error is:

```
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\model\model.class.php on line 11
```

I am new to PDO, and I trying to figure it out but I can't find solution anywhere, can anyone help. Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with PDO per se, but with object-oriented programming.

- You declare `global $db` which you should be using `self::$db` or else making a distinct instance variable.
- You didn't initialize `$db` before you called a method on it. You should set it to `self::getInstance()`.
- You declare a reference to a variable `global $pdo` which you never define and never use. This is just sloppy coding.
- [A model is not a database instance](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html). You should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) in this case.

Comment: tnx a lot, i will deffinitly listen to your advices!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see a very nice example of objects such as these I recommend reviewing this [Database Class](https://github.com/panique/php-login/blob/master/application/libs/Database.php) from the PHP-Login script by panique on GitHub. As well as this [Model class](https://github.com/panique/php-login/blob/master/application/models/overview_model.php) from the same set of scripts. I hope this helps :D